# Transportation problems

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

i'm a master student at the deparment of statistics. And i will prepare a presentation on transportation problems in the course of optimization (or linear programming / mathematical programming)

I have no idea about this topic. I will learn it by myself. Thus, Please books or articles or lecture notes on transportation problems.

PS: My instructor deoes not want to give any suggestion :/ Therefore, i can say no thing about the frame  of the topics.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: To start here is a link to the Standard Transportation Problem: https://www.utdallas.edu/~scniu/OPRE-6201/documents/TP1-Formulation.pdf

Comment: What a good lecture note!!!  thank you:) dear @calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [pdf](http://www.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/480/course.notes/Winston.OperationsResearch.pdf) of a very good clear book on an introductory level: *Operations Research* by Wayne L. Winston.

Another, more advanced source, would be Chvatal's *Linear Programming* ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716715872))

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I look at both. And the books explain very well dear @gt6989b